# Issues were found when checking AAR metadata

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

When i run my Kotlin code on Android Studiou, it says 2 issues were found when checking AAR metadata. How can i solve it?

I don't know why it gives error, but maybe it is something about packages or wrong version of the Android studio. Please help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

i dont get exactly your problem, but try to read the error and apply.
example it may be due to **compilesdk version minimum reuirement** try to upgrade project version or create new project with complieSdk and minSdk 34.or Give more specific details for your problem